# json_agg with postgres union syntax error

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do a query that returns an object that contains a list that has been merged from two different tables with many-many relation to the object.

Here is what i have done:

```
 json_agg((select u.name AS name, u.email AS email
from reports wr
LEFT JOIN 
reportaccountusers rau
ON rau.reportid = wr.id
LEFT JOIN accountusers au
ON rau.accountuserid = au.id
LEFT JOIN users u
ON au.userid = u.id 
where wr.id = 47)
 UNION
(select re.email AS name, re.email AS email
from reports wr
 LEFT JOIN 
reportemails re
ON wr.id = re.reportid
where wr.id = 47)) AS Recipients
```

But however i do it i can't really get it to work.

when i do this:

```
select json_agg((select u.name AS name, u.email AS email
from reports wr
LEFT JOIN 
reportaccountusers rau
ON rau.reportid = wr.id
LEFT JOIN accountusers au
ON rau.accountuserid = au.id
LEFT JOIN users u
ON au.userid = u.id 
where wr.id = 47)
 UNION
(select re.email AS name, re.email AS email
from reports wr
  LEFT JOIN 
reportemails re
ON wr.id = re.reportid
where wr.id = 47)) AS Recipients
```

i get the error :

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION"
LINE 11:      UNION
              ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNION"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 283

Like this:

```
   select json_agg(x) from((select u.name AS name, u.email AS email
from reports wr
LEFT JOIN 
reportaccountusers rau
ON rau.reportid = wr.id
LEFT JOIN accountusers au
ON rau.accountuserid = au.id
LEFT JOIN users u
ON au.userid = u.id 
where wr.id = 47)
 UNION
(select re.email AS name, re.email AS email
from reports wr
  LEFT JOIN 
reportemails re
ON wr.id = re.reportid
where wr.id = 47))x) AS items
```

Comment: Can you tell a little more, like what error messages you get? It helps to create a self-contained test case that exhibits the problem, with data and the desired output. That makes helping so much easier.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is there a good fiddle to do sql with? :)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com or http://rextester.com

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3206ca/3 here is a test :)

Comment: That fiddle contains MySQL code...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/37f49/1 sorry bout that.

Comment: You cannot have `aggregate ((SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...))`. What you can do is `(SELECT aggregate(val) FROM (SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...) a)`.

Comment: like the edit of this post i just did?

Comment: That looks about right with to my naked eye. Try it.